# video don't play with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to get total duration of the video in iPhone. I am using the following code tho get the duration

```
videoPath = [videoPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoPath];
MPMoviePlayerController *mpPlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease]; 
mpPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
[self.view addSubview:mpPlayer.view];
NSLog(@"duration = %f",mpPlayer.duration);
[mpPlayer play];
```

but I don't know why i am not able to get duration of the video also the video is not get play.
can anyone help me to find the solution of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the answers? Did any of those solve your issue? If so, please check the gray checkmark to the left of the solving answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

The duration may not be available prior to the actual playback -> check the duration again when receiving a `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`  (`MPMoviePlayerController.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)` to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check if the path for the video is correct and check if the player is allocated with the correct file url

Comment: I have check it video path is perfect and player is also allocated

Answer (score 0):

```
    videoPath = [videoPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoPath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *mpPlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease]; 
    mpPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:mpPlayer.view];
    NSLog(@"duration = %f",mpPlayer.duration);
    [mpPlayer play];

//add notifications


  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if ((moviePlayer.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) == MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) {
duration = mpPlayer.duration;
NSLog(@"duration = %f",mpPlayer.duration);
}
}
```